# How many distinct dichlorination products can result when isobutane is subjected to free radical chlorination?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> How many distinct dichlorination products can result when isobutane is subjected to free radical chlorination?

I think that three distinct products may result namely
a) 1,1-Dichloro-2-methylpropane
b) 1,2-Dichloro-2-methylpropane
c) 1,3-Dichloro-2-methylpropane

But the book says only two distinct products may form. Can anyone explain how?

Answer (score 1):

The following three products wil be formed:
[image]

Your book may be giving the answer to the number of monochloro products formed, as there are only two distinct monochloro products formed on chlorination of isobutane.